# how to know kubernetes docker config path

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubespray

I install kubernetes using kubespray(release-2.19)

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray.git -b release-2.19 /kubes/kubespray
ansible-playbook -i /kubes/kubespray/inventory/ailab-cluster/hosts.yaml --become --become-user=root /kubes/kubespray/cluster.yml
```

So, I with not command docker.

```
docker

Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with:

snap install docker     # version 20.10.14, or
apt  install docker.io  # version 20.10.12-0ubuntu2~20.04.1
See 'snap info docker' for additional versions.
```

but kubernetes is perfectly install. and normally using.

```
kube-system    calico-kube-controllers-6dd874f784-wlghs   1/1     Running            0        7d1h
kube-system    calico-node-558jd                          1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    calico-node-gftjg                          1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    calico-node-jk6ph                          1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    coredns-76b4fb4578-fklhw                   1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    coredns-76b4fb4578-lvkkk                   1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    dns-autoscaler-7979fb6659-rvzwv            1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-node1                       1/1     Running            1             7d1h
kube-system    kube-apiserver-node2                       1/1     Running            1             7d1h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-node1              1/1     Running            2 (18h ago)   7d1h
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-node2              1/1     Running            1             7d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-2q92h                           1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-66zzb                           1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    kube-proxy-76kf7                           1/1     Running            0             7d1h
kube-system    kube-scheduler-node1                       1/1     Running            1             7d1h ...
```

I using harbor(docker private repo) with ssl, but kubernetes cert is unknown authority

```
Warning  Failed     36m (x4 over 37m)      kubelet            Failed to pull image "192.168.100.102:8088/test_project/af_test:v0.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "192.168.100.102:8088/test_project/af_test:v0.1": failed to resolve reference "192.168.100.102:8088/test_project/af_test:v0.1": failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.100.102:8088/v2/test_project/af_test/manifests/v0.1": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

So. i want find docker configure file.
or how to certification.

plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think Possible issue here is if you have any private repo for Docker so it have to configure in every namespace you are going to use.

In kubernetes if you are using any private repo for pull docker images then you also have to configure 1 secret with private repo details, and you have to mention that secrets in your deployment.yaml file so kubernetes will know from where docker image will found.
For setting private docker repo configuration:
check this example:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/